# Active Directory Users and Computers icons

Tags: powershell, active-directory, treeview, icons

I'm building a GUI in Powershell and I'd like to mimic the look of AD Users and Computers hierarchy in a treeview with an imagelist.  I can't seem to locate the dll or exe file that contains the icons/symbols.  dsadmin.dll doesn't include them either (which I thought they would).  Google hasn't been any help either.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Some of them are included in `C:\Windows\System32\dsuiext.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else hunting for the answer: `C:\Windows\System32\dsadmin.dll`

Comment: amazing, I used resource hacker to get it out and put it in the old Program Manager. Thanks for sharing